# Having trouble automating WinReducer with AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to use AutoHotkey to automatically apply some customizations to all the editions in a Windows 10 `Install.wim` using WinReducer: https://www.winreducer.net/winreducer-ex-100.html. 
The problem I'm having is that once WinReducer reaches this window where you select an edition in the WIM file, I can't seem to interact with either the Combobox or the *Mount* button. 
[image: Window I'm stuck at]

Here is the code I currently have:

```
; ==== Environment setup ====
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
;ListLines, Off

DetectHiddenWindows, On
SetTitleMatchMode, 1
SetControlDelay, 0
CoordMode, Mouse, Client


; ==== Script ====
; Must run with admin privileges

iControlSelector := 1       ; Need to change this to find number of images present in Wim
While iControlSelector < 4  ; Set to the total number of images + 1
{
    WinReducerStartup()
    WinGet, iWinReducerPID, PID, WinReducer EX-100 - v ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe,
    ControlClick, WindowsForms10.COMBOBOX.app.0.141b42a_r36_ad11, Open a Folder ... ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe, , LEFT, 1, NA, 
    Control, Choose, %iControlSelector%, WindowsForms10.COMBOBOX.app.0.141b42a_r36_ad11, Open a Folder ... ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe,
    WinReducerImageProcess("WinReducerEX100.wccf", 0)
    Process, WaitClose, %iWinReducerPID%
    FileDelete, %A_ScriptDir%\WORK\EXTRACT\ExtractedByWinReducer\WinReducerEX100.wccf
    iControlSelector += 1
}

MoveFilesAndFolders(A_ScriptDir . "\WinReducerEX100_x64\WORK\EXTRACT\ExtractedByWinReducer\*", A_ScriptDir . "\NTLite\Extract")

ExitApp



; ==== Functions ====
WinReducerStartup()
{
    Run, %A_ScriptDir%\WinReducerEX100_x64\WinReducerEX100_x64.exe, 
    SkipWinReducerActivateDialog()
    Sleep, 2000
    WaitThenClick("WinReducer EX-100 - v ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe", "WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.141b42a_r36_ad13")
    Sleep, 400
    ControlClick, WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.141b42a_r36_ad15, WinReducer EX-100 - v ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe, , LEFT, 1, NA,
    SkipWinReducerActivateDialog()
    WaitThenClick("Browse For Folder ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe", "Button2")
    WinWait, Open a Folder ... ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe,
    WinActivate, Open a Folder ... ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe,
    Return
}

WinReducerImageProcess(sConfigFile, iSecondPass:=0)
{
    ;ControlClick, WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.141b42a_r36_ad11, Open a Folder ... ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe, , LEFT, 1, NA,
;   ControlClick, MOUNT, Open a Folder ... ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe, , LEFT, 1, NA,
    ControlClick, MOUNT, Open a Folder ... ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe, , LEFT, 1, ,
    SkipWinReducerActivateDialog()
    WinWait, Open a Folder ... ahk_class WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.141b42a_r36_ad1 ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe,
    SkipWinReducerActivateDialog()
    WaitThenClick("WinReducer EX-100 - v ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe", "WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.141b42a_r36_ad12")
    SkipWinReducerActivateDialog()
    WaitThenClick("ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe", "Button1")
    WaitThenClick("WinReducer Custom Configuration File Restore ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe", "Edit2")
    ControlSend, Edit2, ^AD:\Windows_NT_development\WinReducerEX100_x64{Enter}, WinReducer Custom Configuration File Restore ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe,
    ControlClick, DirectUIHWND2, WinReducer Custom Configuration File Restore ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe, , LEFT, 1, NA,
    ControlSend, DirectUIHWND2, ^A%sConfigFile%, WinReducer Custom Configuration File Restore ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe,
    ControlClick, Button1, WinReducer Custom Configuration File Restore ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe, , LEFT, 1, NA,
    WaitThenClick("Activate Unattended Options ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe", "Button1")    ; Okay to delete previous Autounattended.xml
    Sleep, 100
    WaitThenClick("ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe", "Button1")
    If iSecondPass = 1
    {
        CopyFilesAndFolders(A_ScriptDir . "\WinReducerEX100_x64\WORK\MOUNT\Copy-Paste to mount directory\*", A_ScriptDir . "\WinReducerEX100_x64\WORK\MOUNT\TEMP_Windows")
        RunWait, %A_WinDir%\System32\Dism.exe /Image:%A_ScriptDir%\WinReducerEX100_x64\WORK\MOUNT\TEMP_Windows /Import-DefaultAppAssociations:%A_ScriptDir%\WinReducerEX100_x64\WORK\MOUNT\FileAssociations.xml,
        WinActivate, WinReducer EX-100 - v ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe,
    }
    WaitThenClick("WinReducer EX-100 - v ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe", "WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.141b42a_r36_ad17")
    Sleep, 500
    ControlClick, WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.141b42a_r36_ad14, WinReducer EX-100 - v ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe, , LEFT, 1, NA,
    SkipWinReducerActivateDialog()
    WaitThenClick("Start WinReducer Process ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe", "Button1")
    Return
}

SkipWinReducerActivateDialog()
{
    WinWait, Activate your WinReducer Edition ? ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe, 
    ControlClick, WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.141b42a_r36_ad11, Activate your WinReducer Edition ? ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe, , LEFT, 1, NA,
    PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF060, , , Activate your WinReducer Edition ? ahk_exe WinReducerEX100_x64.exe,     ; 0x112 = WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF060 = SC_CLOSE
    Return
}

WaitThenClick(sWinName, sControl)
{
    WinWait, %sWinName%, 
    ControlClick, %sControl%, %sWinName%, , LEFT, 1, NA,
}

MoveFilesAndFolders(sSourcePattern, sDestinationFolder, iDoOverwrite = false)
; Moves all files and folders matching sSourcePattern into the folder named sDestinationFolder and
; returns the number of files/folders that could not be moved. This function requires [v1.0.38+]
; because it uses FileMoveDir's mode 2.
{
    If iDoOverwrite = 1
        iDoOverwrite = 2  ; See FileMoveDir for description of mode 2 vs. 1.
    ; First move all the files (but not the folders):
    FileMove, %sSourcePattern%, %sDestinationFolder%, %iDoOverwrite%
    ; Now move all the folders:
    Loop, %sSourcePattern%, 2  ; 2 means "retrieve folders only".
    {
        FileMoveDir, %A_LoopFileFullPath%, %sDestinationFolder%\%A_LoopFileName%, %iDoOverwrite%
    }
    Return
}

CopyFilesAndFolders(sSourcePattern, sDestinationFolder, iDoOverwrite = false)
; Copies all files and folders matching sSourcePattern into the folder named sDestinationFolder and
; returns the number of files/folders that could not be copied.
{
    ; First copy all the files (but not the folders):
    FileCopy, %sSourcePattern%, %sDestinationFolder%, %iDoOverwrite%
    ; Now copy all the folders:
    Loop, %sSourcePattern%, 2  ; 2 means "retrieve folders only".
    {
        FileCopyDir, %A_LoopFileFullPath%, %sDestinationFolder%\%A_LoopFileName%, %iDoOverwrite%
    }
    Return
}
```

Comment: AutoHotkey can automate conventional GUI with GUI automation commands. If GUI is made with JavaScript or WPF it cannot be automated with GUI automation commands and you need to use image matching and mouse click commands to automate that kind of GUIs.